# Specify alternate compiler and linker to make

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have both a default C/C++ tool set (gcc 4.8) and have recently built and installed 5.2 in its own directory. I want to build some C++ programs using a makefile that uses CC and CXX explicity to compile but uses the implicit built-in rule to link the .o files to build the executable.

When I run make on the makefile, I use the command

```
make all CC=/usr/gcc-5.2.0/bin/gcc-5.2.0 CXX=/usr/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++-5.2.0
```

The compile steps all use the 5.2 compilers but when the executable is build, the default g++ is used to link everything. Now, this happens to work and the results run but it isn't what I want. I tried adding

```
LD=/usr/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++-5.2.0
```

to the make command line but LD is ignored. Without changing the makefile, how can I get the link step to use the 5.2 compiler?

Here is the make file:

```
CPPFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lstdc++
CXX = g++
CC = g++

all: TestSHA3 HashSHA3 HashZeroBytes LongTest sha3sum

debug: override CPPFLAGS += -ggdb
debug: all

SHA3-o3:
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -O3 -c -o SHA3.o SHA3.cpp
o3:  SHA3-o3 all

TestSHA3: TestSHA3.o SHA3.o
HashSHA3: HashSHA3.o SHA3.o
HashZeroBytes: HashZeroBytes.o SHA3.o
LongTest: LongTest.o SHA3.o
sha3sum: sha3sum.o SHA3.o

.PHONY: clean realclean rc debug all o3 SHA3-o3
clean:
        rm SHA3.o TestSHA3.o HashSHA3.o HashZeroBytes.o LongTest.o sha3sum.o
rc: realclean
realclean: clean
        rm TestSHA3 HashSHA3 HashZeroBytes LongTest sha3sum
```

Here is the command:

```
 make all CXX=g++-5.2.0 LD=g++-5.2.0
```

And here are the results of the make:

```
g++-5.2.0  -Wall  -c -o TestSHA3.o TestSHA3.cpp
g++-5.2.0  -Wall  -c -o SHA3.o SHA3.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  TestSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o TestSHA3
g++-5.2.0  -Wall  -c -o HashSHA3.o HashSHA3.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  HashSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o HashSHA3
g++-5.2.0  -Wall  -c -o HashZeroBytes.o HashZeroBytes.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  HashZeroBytes.o SHA3.o   -o HashZeroBytes
g++-5.2.0  -Wall  -c -o LongTest.o LongTest.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  LongTest.o SHA3.o   -o LongTest
g++-5.2.0  -Wall  -c -o sha3sum.o sha3sum.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  sha3sum.o SHA3.o   -o sha3sum
```

Comment: Post the contents of the Makefile. Make doesn't know about C/C++; it only uses the variables `CC` and `LD` if the step rules do.

Comment: Your makefile is incomplete, where is link command there?

Comment: Did you read the text? The linking is done via an implicit rule. The rule is triggered by the lines like "TestSHA3: TestSHA3.o SHA3.o".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
make all CXX=g++-5.2.0 CC=g++-5.2.0
```

The implicit rule for linking uses `CC` ([make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)):

> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called
>   ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS)
>   n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

With your `Makefile` and dummy source files:

```
$ make all CXX=`which g++`
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o TestSHA3.o TestSHA3.cpp
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o SHA3.o SHA3.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  TestSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o TestSHA3
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o HashSHA3.o HashSHA3.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  HashSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o HashSHA3
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o HashZeroBytes.o HashZeroBytes.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  HashZeroBytes.o SHA3.o   -o HashZeroBytes
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o LongTest.o LongTest.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  LongTest.o SHA3.o   -o LongTest
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o sha3sum.o sha3sum.cpp
g++ -lstdc++  sha3sum.o SHA3.o   -o sha3sum

$ make all CC=`which g++`
g++  -Wall  -c -o TestSHA3.o TestSHA3.cpp
g++  -Wall  -c -o SHA3.o SHA3.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  TestSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o TestSHA3
g++  -Wall  -c -o HashSHA3.o HashSHA3.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  HashSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o HashSHA3
g++  -Wall  -c -o HashZeroBytes.o HashZeroBytes.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  HashZeroBytes.o SHA3.o   -o HashZeroBytes
g++  -Wall  -c -o LongTest.o LongTest.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  LongTest.o SHA3.o   -o LongTest
g++  -Wall  -c -o sha3sum.o sha3sum.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  sha3sum.o SHA3.o   -o sha3sum

$ make all CC=`which g++` CXX=`which g++`
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o TestSHA3.o TestSHA3.cpp
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o SHA3.o SHA3.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  TestSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o TestSHA3
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o HashSHA3.o HashSHA3.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  HashSHA3.o SHA3.o   -o HashSHA3
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o HashZeroBytes.o HashZeroBytes.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  HashZeroBytes.o SHA3.o   -o HashZeroBytes
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o LongTest.o LongTest.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  LongTest.o SHA3.o   -o LongTest
/usr/bin/g++  -Wall  -c -o sha3sum.o sha3sum.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -lstdc++  sha3sum.o SHA3.o   -o sha3sum
```

Comment: That works if I define CC=g++-5.2.0. Of course, .c files are compiled using the g++ compiler but I guess that is OK.

Comment: Compiler version aside, linking with `CC=gcc` should work too as long as you have the `-lstdc++` option enabled

Comment: @sizzzzlerz - I was just writing a comment on that - I used it as you had  already `CC` set to `g++` in your project for some reason